# Upsert function for elasicsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I would like to periodically update the data in elasticsearch.

In the file I send in for update, there may be data that already exist in elasticsearh (for update) and data that are new docs (for insert).

Since the data in elasticsearch is managed by auto-created ID,
I have to search the ID by a column "code"(unique) to make sure if a doc already exists, if exists update, otherwise insert.

I wonder if there is any method that is faster than the codes I think of as below.

```
es = Elasticsearch()

# get doc ID by searching(exact match) a code to check if ID exists
res = es.search(index=index_name, doc_type=doc_type, body=body_for_search)
id_dict = dict([('id', doc['_id'])]) for doc in res['hits']['hits’]

# if id exists, update the current doc by id   
# else insert with auto-created id 
If id_dict['id']:
    es.update(index=index_name, id=id_dict['id'], doc_type=doc_type, body=body)
else:
    es.index(index=index_name, doc_type=doc_type, body=body)
```

For example, could there be a method where elasticsearch search the exact match `col["code"]` for you and you can simply "upsert" the data without specifying id?
Any advice would be much appreciated and thank you for your reading.

ps- if we make the `id = col["code"]` it could be much simpler and faster,  but for management issue we can't do it at current stage.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/docs-update.html#upserts

Comment: you can tell elasticsearch to use your own IDs. That way you can just index the doc at the known ID and it will be upserted

Answer (score 0):

1. As @Archit said, use your own ID to lookup document faster
2. Use upsert API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts

Be sure your ID structure respects Lucene good practice:

> If you are using your own ID, try to pick an ID that is friendly to
>   Lucene. Examples include zero-padded sequential IDs, UUID-1, and
>   nanotime; these IDs have consistent, sequential patterns that compress
>   well. In contrast, IDs such as UUID-4 are essentially random and offer
>   poor compression and slow down Lucene.